# How to do mapping in reactjs if data is fetch in other file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a fileone.js file and I am trying to fetch the API data in this file as given below

```
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { ApiUrlConstant } from '../../../../utils/ApiUrlConstant';
import { getTokenu, isLoginu } from "../../../../utils/Token";
const Course = lazy(()=> import('../../../Course'));
const CourseDetails = lazy(()=> import('../../../CourseDetails'));
import Switch from "react-bootstrap/esm/Switch";
import PublicRoute from "../../../Route/Publicroute";
import FallBack from "../../FallBack/FallBack";
import "./Courses.scss";

class fileone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      load: false,
      checkPaid: true,
      page: 0,
    };
    this.token = getTokenu();
  }

  setLoader = () => {
    this.setState({ load: !this.state.load });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(ApiUrlConstant.getApiFullUrl("course.feed"),
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Token " + this.token
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ User: res.data.results[0].user_detail.username, load: false });
          this.setState({ Paid: res.data.results[0].user_paid, load: false });
          this.setState({ CoursList: res.data.results[0].courses_list, load: false });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.setState({ error: error, load: false });
        });
    };

render() {
  return (
    <div className="course-main-feed">        
      <Suspense fallback={<FallBack />}>
        <Switch style={{ paddingLeft: "0px" }}>
          { this.state.User && (this.state.Paid == true) ? <>
            <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={Course} path="/paidcourses" handleToast={this.props.handleToast} exact/>
            <PublicRoute restricted={false} component={CourseDetails} path="/paidcourses/:paidcourse_id" handleToast={this.props.handleToast} />
          </>: null }
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default fileone;
```

In the given code as we can see there is a line inside componentdidmount *this.setState({ CoursList: res.data.results[0].courses_list, load: false });* in this line there are n number of courses object list. I am trying to map this **courses_list** in another file. I tried with the below code but I seems like the data is not getting in this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./Course.scss";

export class Course extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      load: false,
      error: null,
      next: "",
      prev: "",
      menu: false,
    };
  }



  setLoader = () => {
    this.setState({ load: !this.state.load });
  };

  renderArticlesFeed = () => {
    if (this.state.CoursList === 0)
      return (
        <div style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", color: "#f3990f" }}>
          <span>No Courses to display!</span>
        </div>)
        return this.state.CoursList && this.state.CoursList.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="" style={{width: "100%", margin: "none"}} key={item.id}>
              <div className="course-feed-column">
                <div className="">
                {item.title}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          );
        }
      )
  };

  render() {
    const { data, error, load } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
            {this.renderArticlesFeed()}
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Course
```

I am not able to get the value of **{item.id}** and **{item.title}**. Any help from anyone will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from where you get the `courseList` in state. If you want to pass `courseList` from one component to another you could pass it as a prop